# Numba breaking down at the 32 bit limit

Tags: python, python-3.8, numba

In my code which uses the @njit decorator, there is a line:

```
average_distance=d/(n**4)
```

funnily enough, n^4 == 2^32 and I get the error

> ZeroDivisionError: division by zero

which i am only assume is due to an overflow where, once the 32 bit limit is reached, it rolls over to 0.
Is there a way around this at all? I'm very new to numba so i have no idea how to get around this.
Full Code Example:

```
@timer
@njit(nogil=True)
def split_method(n):
    d=0
    for x in range(n):
        for y in range(n):
            p1x=x/n
            p1y=y/n
            for x2 in range(n):
                for y2 in range(n):
                    p2x=x2/n
                    p2y=y2/n
                    d+=((p1x-p2x)**2 + (p1y-p2y)**2)**(1/2)
    average_distance=(d/(n**4))
    return average_distance
```

Comment: Can't you just use a 64bit integer?

Comment: I've never had to do that before. How do I change an integer that way?

Comment: You need to provide a full example

Comment: That method smells like you could get an analytical solution to it -- in any case, it's trivially cached, so you could slap an `@lru_cache()` on it...

Comment: I can't reproduce the error (Python 3.8, Numba 0.53.1).
Numba types depend on the parameters passed to the function when no explicit signature is provided. If `n` is an int it's because you are passing an int to the function. You can convert `n` to float in `average_distance = d / float(n) ** 4`.